# *.asmx webservice debugging without access to Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asmx

I need to debug some old legacy web application where backend is written in asp (*.asmx files).

Is there any way to add some log/ dump any variable inside function without access to Visual Studio (it can be just a simple dump to file on server)?

Comment: You can enable tracing to dump the entire messages to disk, but apart from that you're going to need a debugger and the source.

Comment: I have an access to source ( I can also change it ), how to enable such dump ?

Comment: [MSDN: Enabling Tracing in ASP.NET Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb885203(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I'm curious: if you don't have visual studio how do you "change" the source ?

Comment: @Alex, Well, I have access to server files, and those *.asmx files seems to be just plain text files, or do I missinig something ?

Comment: Ah I see, I misread the question as they being aspnet